# how to have text change when you hover over it?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make a box that displays text when you hover over it.
this is the code I have currently:

```
<style>
/* WHILE HOVERED */  
.one:hover {  
    box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black; 
    background: #00576f;  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0c5f85, #0b5273 50%, #024869 51%, #003853);  
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottombottom, color-stop(0, #0c5f85), color-stop(.5, #0b5273), color-stop(.51, #024869), to(#003853));  
    }  

/* WHILE BEING CLICKED */  
.one:active {  }  

.other {  
 width: 200px;  
 height: 200px;  
 line-height: 100px;  
 color: white;  
 text-decoration: none;  
 font-size: 50px;  
 font-family: helvetica, arial;  
 font-weight: bold;  
 display: block;  
 text-align: center;  
 position: relative;  
margin-top: 10px auto;

/* BACKGROUND GRADIENTS */  
 background: #00485c;  






</style>
<body>
<center><div class="other one"/div></center>
</body>
```

I know that there is probably a simpler way to do what I have so far, but I only need to know how to make text appear in the square when you hover over it.
thanks.

Comment: This seems more suited to javascript/jquery.

Comment: I agree with Bernie. When you need to use a hammer, use a hammer.

Comment: @Bernie There's no reason for this to depend on JS. It can be achieved in CSS in a variety of ways.

Comment: @flem, however, it seems more suited to jquery, as I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do this in pure CSS, but JavaScript may be the better option if you're unable to change the HTML markup. At any rate:

```
.one:hover:after {
    content: "My text here!"
}
```

Comment: Note that this adds the content *outside* the div. It also requires that your page content exist in the CSS file. That's not great practice.